# Conditions on a piecewise function to ensure differentiability.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $g:(-a,0) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and $h:[0,a) \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $(0,a)$. Suppose further that $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}g(x) = h(0)$ and $\lim_{0^{+}}h'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^{-}}g'(x) = L$. Define 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) \; x < 0 \\
h(x) \; x \geq 0
\end{cases}
$$
Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ or find a counterexample that shows that $f$ is not necessarily differentiable at $0$.

I want to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0$. Here's where I get stuck:

We want that bound $|\frac{f(a) - h(0)}{a} - L|$ by choosing $a$ sufficiently close to zero. We first consider the case when $a > 0$. By triangle inequality we have
$$
\left|\frac{h(a) - h(0)}{a} - L\right| \leq \left|\frac{h(a) - h(0)}{a} - h'(a)\right| + \left|h'(a) - L\right|. 
$$
We can easily bound $|h'(a) - L|$ by choosing small enough $\delta$, however I've really struggled to bound $\left|\frac{h(a) - h(0)}{a} - h'(a)\right|$. The case for which $a < 0$ we also run into a similar problem. I've tried to prove this by contradiction as well but that was not panning out either. I think that maybe the $f'(0)$ is guaranteed to exist but not necessarily equal to $L$.

I would love either a full solution or a hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may apply L'Hôpital's rule so that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} g'(x) =L,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} h'(x) =L.
\end{align*}
Hence, $f'(0)$ exists and must be equal to $L$.

Answer (score 2):

In any of the cases, you should use [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem) (RT). 
First, take $a>0$, by RT, it exists $0<c<a$ (set $c=c(a)$) such that $\frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a}=f'(c(a))$. From 
the hypotheses, you get $lim_{a\to 0_+} f'(c(a))=L$ and then
$$
lim_{a\to 0_+} \frac{f(a)-f(0)}{a}=L
$$ 
which proves the claim. The reasoning is exactly the same for $a<0$.